# Remove yellow rectangles when Russian in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have yellow rectangles around Russian letters in VSCode when write e.g. Python code. How to remove this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I've added to settings.json `"editor.unicodeHighlight.ambiguousCharacters": false`. And yellow rectangles've disappeared